# Making platform game, need method to stop running

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a platform game in flash.

I have a goal class(the class which contains code for the goal sprite, where when you hit it, it continues to next part of game).

Inside the goal constructor, 2 event listeners are added, they are as follows:

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

The beginClass function is fine, and only runs once, but eFrame is what checks if the player has hit the goal, so it is constantly running. The problem is, once the player hits the goal, eFrame continues to run, while in a menu describing the next scene to the player. My eFrame function is below.

```
    private function eFrame(event:Event):void{
        if(hitTestObject(_root.mcMain)){
            var lastScore:int = _root.mainScore;
            _root.mainScore = lastScore;
            while (_root.lvlHolder.numChildren > 0) {
                    _root.lvlHolder.removeChildAt(0);
            }
            _root.mcMain.removeChildAt(0);
            _root.isInCut = true;
            if (_root.lvlCurrent == 1) {
                _root.gotoAndStop(2);
            } else if (_root.lvlCurrent == 2) {
                _root.gotoAndStop(3);
            } else if (_root.lvlCurrent == 3) {
                _root.gotoAndStop(4);
            }
        }
    }
```

Frames 2, 3, 4, are frames with just text and a button that display a message to the player, and then the player hits continue. My problem is that eFrame is still trying to be run, but the class has not been instantiated, and the method is causing extreme amounts of lag once the player continues.

Answer (score 2):

Inside Goal, what's the point of _root?

Anyway here's what I've done: 
Change the event `ADDED` to `ADDED_TO_STAGE`, that way, when the event is fired we know this Sprite has a `stage` property.

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, beginClass);
```

Remove the `eFrame` event from the constructor. Add it to `beginClass`, with `stage`, like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

Now in `eFrame`, you can awesomely remove the event with the stage reference. It didn't work earlier because the reference was wrong (whatever it was with the `_root` variable).

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

BUT - remember to do it before this part of your code:

```
while (_root.lvlHolder.numChildren > 0) {
    _root.lvlHolder.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

because when the sprite is removed, it won't have the `stage` property anymore. Just remember to clean up events in all possible scenarios. I'm not entirely sure `stage` is the right place to place your enter frame event, I just assumed so because of what you earlier called _root.

Answer (score 0):

Inside eFrame() stop the event listener:

removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);

Comment: I did that, but it's still doing it. When I got to frame 2, the code from frame 1 isn't run right? Because that's where the Goal class is called.

Answer (score 0):

you're adding eventListener to stage so try this:

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

or

```
parent.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```

or

```
event.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
```