# Method won't stop running when I switch to new frame, why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making platform game, need method to stop running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691540/making-platform-game-need-method-to-stop-running)

I am making a small flash game for my Geometry class. Here's a little rundown of how it works.

Basically you play as a circle, trying to find it's circumference. You have to beat a level, and then you find out a small bit of information to help you find your circumference.

The main code of the game is in the actions for frame 1, however there are a few other classes. Everything is almost working, except when I transition from frame 1, to frame 2(the frame that the cutscene type thing is on), it keeps running the eFrame method from the Goal class.

Can anyone try and find out why the eFrame method won't stop running when I switch to frame 2?

This link is a .zip of the .fla + .as files: http://www.mediafire.com/?1du9taja0o1luuq

Please let me know what you see wrong with it.